# Maximum modulus theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I do not understand the proof for the maximum modulus theorem done with the open mapping theorem. Unfortunately my notes are a little bit cryptic.

What I understand: Let $z_0$ be the maximum that is not on the boundary of a holomorphic non-constant function $f$ If we choose an open ball $D_r(z_0)$, then the image $f(D_r(z_0))$ is also an open ball around $z_0$ by the OMT.

Then my notes say $f(D_r(z_0))\subset\overline{D_{|f(z_0)|}(z_0)}$ and that $\overline{D_{|f(z_0)|}(z_0)}$ is not neighbourhood of $f(z_0)$ and therefore $f(z_0)$ must be constant by the OMT, but I struggle heavily to understand this. How do I get a maximum that is bigger than $z_0$? Why do I take a closed ball with radius $|f(z_0)|$? Can someone explain this to me?

Unfortunately most proofs I found are not using the OMT and the identity theorem, but I have to do it with atleast the OMT.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it should be
$$ \tag{*}
f(D_r(z_0))\subset\overline{D_{|f(z_0)|}(0)}
$$
which is true because $|f(z)| \le |f(z_0)|$ for all $z \in D_r(z_0)$.
Also note that $f(z_0)$ is on the *boundary* of $\overline{D_{|f(z_0)|}(0)}$ .

The open mapping theorem states that $f(D_r(z_0))$ is an open set,
in particular $f(z_0)$ must have a open neighbourhood $U$ such
that $f(z_0) \in U \subset f(D_r(z_0))$.

On the other hand, every open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(z_0)$ contains
points *outside* of $\overline{D_{|f(z_0)|}(0)}$.
This gives a contradiction
to $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understand it more or less. Have a great day / night.